# Should the "quality" tag be disambiguated?

Tags: discussion, tags

When asking my first question, I noticed we have a "quality" tag.

I used it to ask about the quality of the 3D printer in my question, but most other uses are about the quality of the prints.

Should we have separate tags, e.g. "printer-quality" and "print-quality"?

Answer (score 4):

"print-quality" is a better (more specific) tag than "quality", but I don't think we should have a "printer-quality" tag. While discussions about print quality and how to improve it can be reasonably objective, questions asking about printer quality are likely to be primarily opinion-based and off-topic for this site.

Comment: Isn't there a more-technical/exacting term to describe the "quality"/precision of the output... something akin to the "resolution" in the 2D printing world?

Comment: I agree with @RobertCartaino, quality doesn't quite seem to be the right phrase. I don't have a better option though off the top of my head

Comment: I agree with this answer, but I don't feel we need a "printer-quality" tag because it would likely lead to lots of "Is this a good printer?" style questions.

Comment: @ChaseCromwell Isn't that basically what this answer says?

Comment: @RobertCartaino I think "print-quality" is fine. Resolution can be determined objectively, but problem with print quality like stringing, blobs or gaps in the print can't be measured. "Resolution" could possibly be another tag, but as 99.9% of resolution talk would be marketing talk and lies I'd like to avoid that one.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden That is a good point, there isn't an exact metric for overall quality